# Python pyinstaller create exe with fixed args

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, pyinstaller

How can i set fixed args when converting py to exe? I'm using PyInstaller library on python. For example when Flask page requested i'll call PyInstaller for create exe. I tried this but PyInstaller detecting args as file path.

```
python -m PyInstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --name "TestEXE" --clean  "C:/Users/harms/Desktop/Python/main.py <arg1> <arg2>"
```

if you think i can't do this with this library please suggest library like pyinstaller in python.

Comment: If all the settings are the same every time you should use a .spec file https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html

Comment: nope, every time args will be change to user specific settings

Comment: I would try to add the args one at a time and see where does it crash and arrange them in a way pyinstaller accepts

Comment: What program are you trying to pass said arguments to? The one you're building with PyInstaller?